# Почему не срабатывает проверка

Tags: php, wordpress

По многочисленным рекомендациям решил использовать для определения телефонов/планшетов mobile detect.

Подключил через functions.php

```
require_once 'wp-content/themes/minecraft/mobile_detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
```

Затем использую в sidebar.php

```
<?php if(!$detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet()){ ?>
<div class="banner">
    ...
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Все работает. Однако стоит сделать проверку где-нибудь еще header, single и т.д. - она не срабатывает и код после проверки полностью обрезается.

С чем может быть это связано?

**Обновление №1**

Кстати, если сделать проверку больше, чем один раз в одном файле (например, sidebar.php) - все работает. Может, я как-то не так подключаю?

**Обновление №2**

```
Notice: Undefined variable: detect in /home/d/dfb38061/сайт.ru/public_html/wp-content/themes/minecraft/header.php on line 13 Fatal error: Call to a member function isMobile() on a non-object in /home/d/dfb38061/сайт.ru/public_html/wp-content/themes/minecraft/header.php on line 13
```

Comment: А что Вы имеете в виду под фразой "... код после проверки полностью обрезается." ?

Comment: @Nicholas Essen http://ssmaker.ru/227cf649.jpg а должен http://ssmaker.ru/89ab61fe.jpg

Comment: @rodion, почитайте про область видимости функций. Вкратце: $detect вы объявляете в одной области видимости, а подключаемые файлы существуют в другой. Создавайте объект $detect прямо там, где он требуется.

Comment: @Etki то есть просто делать проверку так? http://ssmaker.ru/f3b04574.png

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ошибке undefined вам нужно определить переменную класса Mobile_Detect:
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
Если вы ее уже где-то объявляли и все равно эта ошибка выскакивает - у вас проблема с областью видимости переменной. Объявите ее глобально.